# What would make a script to get stdout returns differently on different locations?

Tags: terminal, stdout, deno, get-childitem

```js
import * as path from "https://deno.land/std@0.188.0/path/mod.ts";
async function getStdout() {
    const dirname = path.dirname(path.fromFileUrl(import.meta.url))
    const cmd = new Deno.Command("pwsh", { args: ['-c', 'ls', dirname] });
    const { _code, stdout, _stderr } = await cmd.output();
    const decodedStdout = new TextDecoder().decode(stdout)
    console.log(decodedStdout)
}
await getStdout()
```

This script is simply to get the path of it, run `pwsh -c ls $dirname` and print the result back. If running on folder A it works fine, but on folder B it returns nothing. Surely there are files on B; running `ls` on B is fine.

**However**, if I change the command from `ls` to `echo`, then it works again.

What makes this happens?

Answer (score 0):

After a sleep I realize I didn't log the code and the stderr. This helps me debug:

```js
if (code !== 0) {
    console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(stderr))
}
```

In my case, it's because I use spaces in filenames. The fix is to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Full script:

```js
import * as path from "https://deno.land/std@0.188.0/path/mod.ts";
async function getStdout() {
    const dirname = path.dirname(path.fromFileUrl(import.meta.url))
    console.log(dirname)
    const cmd = new Deno.Command("pwsh", { args: ['-c', 'ls', `'${dirname}'`] });
    const { code, stdout, stderr } = await cmd.output();
    const decodedStdout = new TextDecoder().decode(stdout)
    console.log(decodedStdout)

    if (code !== 0) {
        console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(stderr))
    }
}
await getStdout()
```

Take a look at [Should I avoid using spaces in my filenames?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/355908/192731)